# create python GUI to execute another python script

Tags: python, user-interface, subprocess, wxpython

My question is about how to create a GUI (desktop or web) that will call another application (python script) when a button is clicked in the GUI.

The GUI will have several `text fields` and a `button`, and once the `button` is clicked, the GUI will launch another python script and pass the contents of the GUI's `text fields` as arguments into the called script.

An additional requirement is that the GUI must be able to handle *multiple requests at the same time*. That is, several end users may open the GUI and fill out the `text fields` and submit their jobs *simultaneously*. The GUI should be able to handle this.

Also, since the GUI calls another python script, if I modify some internal computations in the python script at some point in the future, the GUI will still work since the GUI - script interface does not change.

Any solutions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried doing? As is this question sounds like you are asking us to write code for you?

Comment: no, I'm asking the methodology, I believe this is a typical front end back end problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the definition of GET and POST operations in HTTP.

You will need a web server like Flask or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/).  I suggest [using flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#http-methods) for first timers.  A webserver takes the url http://somesite.com/my_function, and internally figures out that the URL part **/my_function** should run `my_function()`.  But you will never ever want to call `my_function()` directly from a web page or an application because of *security reasons.

You can make the buttons in a web page (every OS has a browser, just use that)
It has the backend to handle several connections at once.  (if you need more connections handled simultaneously, hook it up to [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/))

Web servers are built to handle multiple connections.  Each connection is separate even though other people are running the same function. It only looks like it can do things at once but the processor can only handle one thing at a time but it does it so fast it looks like every process/thread is getting handled in a timely manner.